# What does strptime do with the information it reads/converts?

Tags: c, posix, standards-compliance, strptime

The specification for `strptime`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html

is mostly clear on the possible conversion specifications and what input they require. However, there seems to be no specification for how this function stores the results in the `struct tm`. What is supposed to happen if multiple specifiers read partly or wholly conflicting data. A simple example would be the presence of both `%m` and `%b` (or even duplicate `%m`'s) reading conflicting months, but perhaps a more interesting example is when `%d` (day of month) and `%a` (day of week) conflict. Which takes precedence? Is `strptime` even supposed to ensure a consistent output in the `struct tm`, or simply store the fields as-read? Certain things like `%W` (week of year) have no direct representation in `struct tm`, so I would assume they must result in the generation of derived output based on other fields, but it's unclear when this applies.

I realize since the specification seems to be lacking, I may be asking for an answer that simply doesn't exist, but things that could characterize a helpful answer would be:

- behavior of historical implementations on which the standardized function was based.
- citations of relevant defect reports
- links to past discussions of the topic (mailing lists, bug trackers, usenet, etc.)
- other related standards for time parsing

Answer (score 2):

The additional fields can be used for verification of the date.  Validation and verification, you can convert the string to a series of numbers that reresent a date, then you must verify that all those numbers refer to one correct date, e.g. day-of-week is correct,  if the date is not valid then `strptime` returns `NULL`.

Comment: So everything `strptime` converts must be *consistent*, but not necessarily *complete*?

Comment: @R.. that's what I would go with being *reasonable* behaviour.  Obviously some implementations need not verify consistency and just return garbage ala GIGO.

Comment: What about derived values when it's not a matter of consistency? For example if I read the day-of-year and year, can I expect to be able to find meaningful values in the month, day-of-month, and day-of-week fields, or only in the day-of-year and year fields? Surely if year is omitted `strptime` could not provide any of that except the day-of-year value it read...

Comment: @R.. well the options are either 0 (the start of the epoch), or take the values from the current time.  So if you provide "Friday" it would assume 2011.  However `man strptime` shows it only sets the values you provide, so a third option.